# Clarification on the statement of Schwarz Lemma

Tags: complex-analysis

In Complex Analysis, in the classical Schwarz Lemma, some authors consider a function $f:\mathbb D\to\mathbb {\overline D}$, ($\mathbb D$ is the open unit disc) but actually |f(z)| can never be equal to 1 because in such a case the conclusion drawn from the Lemma that $|f(z)|\le|z|$ will give a contradiction 1<1. Why is the codomain chosen as $\mathbb {\overline D}$ instead of $\mathbb D$?

Comment: cannot say the motivation of a given author, but this version is (slightly) stronger and it applies to the Schur class (which consists precisely of holomorphic functions $f:\mathbb D\to\mathbb {\overline D}$ which is a compact class of analytic functions hence bunch of theorems in functional analysis apply directly rather than the relatively compact class obtained if we restrict the image to the open disc)

Comment: @Conrad Thank you for the wonderful insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it looks like quite simple a reason to me: because that way the theorem is stronger. If the hypothesis of the theorem were that $f$ is a function from $\Bbb D$ to $\Bbb D$, then you can only use this theorem if you have proved that $\lvert f(z)\rvert<1$ for all $\lvert z\rvert<1$. On the other hand, if you have the hypothesis $f:\Bbb D\to\overline{\Bbb D}$, then you can use the theorem even if you only have proved $\lvert f(z)\rvert\le1$ (and, possibly, conclude that $\lvert f(z)\rvert<1$ for all $z\in\Bbb D$).

Comment: Thank you for the nice insight. Can f(z)=1 ?? Is it possible?? Then why artificially enlarge the co domain?

Comment: @LawrenceMano no, it can't, at least not if $f(0)=0$. Because if it could be 1, then the maximum principle would guarantee that $f$ is constant, but a constant function can't assume 0 *and* 1 as values.

Comment: @LawrenceMano It isn't possible, and $\overline{\Bbb D}$-Schwarz proves immediately. $\Bbb D$-Schwarz needs an additional use of maximum principle. It's clear that if you are working in a context where every fundational fact about complex analysis may be taken as an axiom, then you have at least three or four ways to exclude the possibility that a holomorphic function $\Bbb D\to\overline{\Bbb D}$ has range containing $0$ and an element of $S^1$. One of them is by using $\overline{\Bbb D}$-Schwarz. Another might be using $\Bbb D$-Schwarz and something else.